# Firefox. How to make border color different than text?

Tags: asp.net, html, css, firefox

I have a problem in one of my GridView headers in my ASP.net website. I want to show white text on green background color in my header cells.  I also want to keep my border color on those cells black.

Here is the CSS I'm using for the headers:

```
.myHeaders
{    
    color: White;
    font-size: 7pt;
    background-color: Green;
    border-color: Black
}
```

I'm referencing it in the Gridview with the HeaderStyle property:

```
<HeaderStyle CssClass="myHeaders" />
```

This works fine in Chrome and IE, but in firefox the border-color gets set to the same value as the forecolor!  How can I get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll get more help if you show the generated html.

Comment: Don't know anything 'bout ASP, but why are you using `CssClass` instead of `class`?

Comment: @Niklas_R: CssClass is the server-side attribute that maps to client-side `class`.

Comment: @Niklas: HeaderStyle is a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.headerstyle.aspx) of the ASP.NET control GridView(which normally is rendered as Table) and this has a property [CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.cssclass.aspx) which actually is(will be rendered as) the CSS-Class. So you can translate this question to "border-color css on table-cells is not applied in Firefox".

Answer (score 3):

Firefox [does not support](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/293) `border-color` on table elements. Just use the `border` shorthand property (`border: 1px solid black`). That should also work in other browsers.

Comment: The page linked to is about the HTML attribute `bordercolor`. Nothing to do with CSS support.

Comment: True, but empirical testing in FF10 (using Firebug to add a style attribute set to "border-color: Black" and then "border-color: black") leads me to believe that the link applies to CSS style attributes as well. That same empirical testing worked like a charm when using Firebug to add a style attribute set to either "border: 1px solid Black" or "border: 1px solid black".

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just right-click your GridView and choose "AutoFormat" so that you can customize colors for your GridView. ?

Answer (score 1):

Using border-color by itself apparently does not work. You should use at least border-style to set the border first.

```
.myHeaders
{    
    color: White;
    font-size: 7pt;
    background-color: Green;
    border-style: Solid;
    border-color: Black
}
```

Comment: The initial value of `border-style` is `none`, so setting `border-color` alone does not create a border. But the situation must be more complicated, since the question says “This works fine in Chrome and IE.”

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Chances are the page is using border-collapse and then depenging on default UA stylesheets which differ....

Answer (score 0):

You're settings the color of a row or `tr`-tag. This means that any child element inside the row inherits this color. Firefox follows the CSS-rules, which dictate that all four borders should have a color defined, if they don't, the default color will be used, i.e. `color: red`.

```
.myHeaders {
    color: Red;
}
```

This is why every border turns red (or white, in your case).
You should set the border color of any sibling to inherit. This will force Firefox to ignore the color and find the closest border-color definition in it's inherited tree.

```
tr.myHeaders > td, tr.myHeaders > th {
    border-color: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ended up adding:

```
foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
{
    tc.Attributes["style"] = "border-color: Black";
}
```

In the RowDataBound event of my GridView.  This worked.

I got the idea from:
http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2009/05/31/Set-Color-of-GridLines-in-Gridview.aspx

I'm unhappy that I had to use a code-behind solution, but don't feel like spending more time on it right now!  Thanks for all your posts!

Comment: I'm still trying to get this without using a code behind solution.  The code above is also overkill, it needs to only be setting the style on header table cells

Comment: I think it was a problem related to the GridLines property.  When set to "Both", the problem occurs